# Want to Know the Use of Android JUnit Test in eclipse?

Tags: android, junit

I am a beginner in Android Devlopment and want to Know the use of JUnit Test in android development using Eclipse, if possible please suggest me some tutorial for learning Android JUnit test, and Please let me know why we use it, what is the benifit of it.

Comment: follow this link: http://junit.org/ and check out the "Usage and Idioms" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JUnit** in version 4.x is a test framework which uses annotations to identify methods that specify a test.

Typically a **JUnit** test is a method contained in a class which is only used for testing. This is called a **Test class**.

To write a test with the **JUnit 4.x** framework you annotate a method with the **@org.junit.Test** annotation.

In this method you use a method provided by the JUnit framework to check the expected result of the code execution versus the actual result.

For an example regarding JUnit Test go through below link..http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: @Sandeep, he provided you with a link to a tutorial. Is that tutorial too technical also?

Answer (score 0):

Junit is a unit testing framework. Junit alongwith robotium is used to automate android application testing.
Robtium provides support for UI automation wheres Junit is the base framework for writing unit test cases.

Read these links for starting in Junit

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html